# Python sort in unproper manner

Tags: python, list, sorting

My code

```
class getCol:
    matrix = []
    def __init__(self, file, delim=" "):
        with open(file, 'rU') as f:
            getCol.matrix =  [filter(None, l.split(delim)) for l in f]

    def __getitem__ (self, key):
        column = []
        for row in getCol.matrix:
            try:
                column.append(row[key])
            except IndexError:
                # pass
                column.append("")
        return column

list1 = getCol('/home/milenko/EDIs/site1/newst2.txt')[0]
list2 = getCol('/home/milenko/EDIs/site2/newst2.txt')[0]
list3 = getCol('/home/milenko/EDIs/site3/newst2.txt')[0]
list4 = getCol('/home/milenko/EDIs/site4/newst2.txt')[0]
list5 = getCol('/home/milenko/EDIs/site5/newst2.txt')[0]
list6 = getCol('/home/milenko/EDIs/site6/newst2.txt')[0]
list7 = getCol('/home/milenko/EDIs/site7/newst2.txt')[0]
list8 = getCol('/home/milenko/EDIs/site8/newst2.txt')[0]
list9 = getCol('/home/milenko/EDIs/site9/newst2.txt')[0]
list10 = getCol('/home/milenko/EDIs/site10/newst2.txt')[0]
list11 = getCol('/home/milenko/EDIs/site11/newst2.txt')[0]
list12 = getCol('/home/milenko/EDIs/site12/newst2.txt')[0]
list13 = getCol('/home/milenko/EDIs/site13/newst2.txt')[0]
list14 = getCol('/home/milenko/EDIs/site14/newst2.txt')[0]
list15 = getCol('/home/milenko/EDIs/site15/newst2.txt')[0]

list_of_lists = []
list_of_lists.append(list1)
list_of_lists.append(list2)
list_of_lists.append(list3)
list_of_lists.append(list4)
list_of_lists.append(list5)
list_of_lists.append(list6)
list_of_lists.append(list7)
list_of_lists.append(list8)
list_of_lists.append(list9)
list_of_lists.append(list10)
list_of_lists.append(list11)
list_of_lists.append(list12)
list_of_lists.append(list13)
list_of_lists.append(list14)
list_of_lists.append(list15)

result = []

# Loop the inner lists from list_of_lists, this will be list1, list2, list3...
for inner_list in list_of_lists:
    # Loop each element of the inner lists
    for element in inner_list:
        # Make sure the element is not already in the result (this can also be done with sets)
        if element not in result:
            # Add the inner element to result
            result.append(element)

# Sort the result
result = sorted(result)
print("\n".join(map(str, result)))
```

But problem is here

```
1.92413
10.15704
1026.00000
10260.00000
10672.43359
11.81549
1104.06055
114.21478
12.00000
12415.04102
1284.33289
13.74474
132.00000
132.86391
1376.00000
13760.00000
14442.18457
1494.04028
15.00000
```

I just want normal ordering from smallest to largest.How should I solve this?Is there any other alternative to `sort`?

Comment: It looks like the items are being treated as text, and thus are being sorted alphabetically.  If you want to sort them numerically, you'll have to convert the values using the `float()` built-in function.

Comment: Try `result = sorted(result, key=float)`

Comment: @MartinEvans Yes,this works!

Comment: What do you mean *Is there any other alternative to sort?* Do you want to make `sorted` work properly? If so, `sorted(result, key=float) `

Comment: @dawg Yes,I got it now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's sorting as strings. To sort as numbers, use the `key` argument:

```
result = sorted(result, key=float)
```

This converts each string to a float for sorting purposes, but leaves the
data as is.

Since you're assigning the result to the same identifier, you can also:

```
result.sort(key=float)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the values in your list from strings to a numeric type like floats.